# Unable to release assistant action because of uncompleted steps, that are completed

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm quite new to the world of google home/assistant, but I've tried out the new Actions builder, which seems really good and intuitive. I have added the methods of invocation, an intent that triggers an inline webhook function, and filled out all the mandatory fields under "Deploy" for both languages. Testing works as expected in simulation (except not in my native language, Norwegian).

But when I try to create an alpha release, it says "Missing info", and that i should navigate to the "Overview" to see what's missing.

[image: create release]

I head over to the overview only to see that multiple things are missing (in both English and Norwegian). Like "Decide how your Action is invoked" under "Quick setup".
[image: overview]

I click on the link, which brings me to settings:
[image: action settings]

There I can "Edit main invocation handling", which brings med further to the main invocation screen:
[image: main invocation]

As far as I can tell, everything about main invocation is in order, or is it something I'm not seeing here? It also says that there are missing information required for the action directory, among other things for the Norwegian language, that are also present.

PS: Pardon any misspellings, English is not my native language.

UPDATE: As for the English language, it was the name that caused the troubles. "My medicines" contained "My", that apparently don't count, which then caused the name to result to "Medicines", and it's not allowed with single word names. After solving this, I was able to create a release for the English language. But I'm still not sure how to deal with the Norwegian language tho.

UPDATE 2: I ended up just removing Norwegian from the Language settings, and adding it again. Then refilling the mandatory fields and translations. Then it worked!

Answer (score 0):

For the English language, it was the name that caused the troubles. "My medicines" contained "My", that apparently don't count, which then caused the name to result to "Medicines", and it's not allowed with single word names. After solving this, I was able to create a release for the English language.

I was still unable to create a release for the Norwegian language, so I ended up just removing Norwegian from the Language settings, and adding it again. Then refilling the mandatory fields and translations. Then it worked!I was able to create and release in both my languages.